# Using a custom R generator function with fit_generator (Keras, R)

Tags: r, keras, image-recognition

I'd like to train a convolutional network to solve a multi-class, multi-label problem on image data. Due to the nature of the data, and for reasons I'll spare you, it would be best if I could use a custom R generator function to feed to the `fit_generator` command, instead of its built-in `image_data_generator` and `flow_images_from_directory` commands (which I was successfully able to get working, just not for this particular problem).

Here (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/keras/versions/2.2.0/topics/fit_generator) it says that I can do just that, without giving any examples. So I tried the following. Here is an extremely stripped down example of what I'm trying to do (this code is entirely self contained):

```
library(keras)
library(reticulate)      #for py_iterator function

play.network = keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(10)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "relu")

play.network %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "mse"
)

mikes.custom.generator.function = function()     #generates a 2-list of a random 1 x 10 array, and a scalar
{
  new.func = function()
 {
    arr = array(dim = c(1,10))
    arr[,] = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)/10
    return(list(arr,runif(1)))
  }
}

mikes.custom.iterator = py_iterator(mikes.custom.generator.function())              #creates a python iterator object

generator_next(mikes.custom.iterator)                 #correctly returns a 2-member list consisting of a 1 x 10 array, and a scalar
generator_next(mikes.custom.iterator)[[1]]            #a 1 x 10 array
generator_next(mikes.custom.iterator)[[2]]            #a scalar

#try to fit with "fit_generator":

play.network %>% fit_generator(                       #FREEZES.
  mikes.custom.iterator,
  steps_per_epoch = 1,
  epochs = 1
)
```

The thing freezes at training time, without giving me an error message or anything. I also tried it with a custom image data generator for my original problem, same result.

Note that this network trains just fine if I just use `fit` and input the training data manually:

```
play.network %>% fit(generator_next(mikes.custom.iterator)[[1]],generator_next(mikes.custom.iterator)[[2]], epochs = 1, batch_size = 1)      

#trains just fine
```

I think I know the problem, but I don't know the solution. If you ask it for the class of my custom iterator, it gives

```
class(mikes.custom.iterator)

[1] "python.builtin.iterator"  "rpytools.generator.RGenerator" "python.builtin.object"
```

whereas if I build an iterator using the builtin `image_data_generator` and `flow_images_from_directory` commands, it gives

```
train_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)

class(train_datagen)

[1] "keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator" "keras_preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator" "python.builtin.object"

train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  train_datagen,
  ....
)

class(train_generator)

[1] "python.builtin.iterator" "keras_preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator" "keras_preprocessing.image.Iterator"        "tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils.Sequence" "python.builtin.object"
```

So my guess is that `train_datagen` and/or `train_generator` have attributes that `mikes.custom.iterator` does not, and `fit_generator` is trying to call upon `mikes.custom.iterator` using functions other than the basic `generator_next` (which is in theory all it should really need). But I don't know what they may be, or how to build `mikes.custom.iterator` correctly, even after searching for two hours online.

Help anyone?